# Limit of showing product in one line and put dot

Tags: css

I use the following code to put title in one line but, if the last word in long, it put `...` instead of word, is there any way to put few letter of word not completely put ...

```
.title {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1; 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options in my brain.

1.

```css
.title {
  width: 230px;
  height: 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, tempore?
</div>
```

2.

```css
.title {
  width: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, tempore?
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in php

```
function custom_echo($x, $length)
{
if(strlen($x)<=$length)
{
echo $x;
}
else
{
$y=substr($x,0,$length) . '...';
echo $y;
}
}
```

put your txt in var

```
$txt="Hello World!";
echo custom_echo($txt, 10) ;
```

result:
Hello Worl

**Edit**
if you not use php

```
.title{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
  }
```

html code:

```
<p class='title'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!</p>
```